# How to dynamically update label texts in kivy that is imported from excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a questionnaire form in kivy. I have added few label widgets in my GUI. **I don't want to define label texts statically in my code**, instead my objective is to **dynamically update label texts that is fetched from an excel file.**

For example: my excel file has 2 questions:

1. Name of the company?
2. Department?

I have 2 label widgets in my GUI, and the text of  widgets should be:

1. Name of the company?
2. Department?

respectively and has to be dynamically fetched from the excel file.

I encountered an error when i tried to run my code.

**Questionnaire.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import pandas as pd

class FetchData():
    file = pd.read_excel("Questionnaire.xlsx")
    Quest = file['QUESTIONS']

class Questions(Widget):
    Data = FetchData().Quest
    qvars =[]

    company = ObjectProperty(None)
    department = ObjectProperty(None)

    qvars.append(company)
    qvars.append(department)

    def validate(self):
        for i in range(len(self.qvars)):
            self.qvars[i].text = self.Data[i]

class QuestionnaireApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Questions()

if __name__=="__main__":
    QuestionnaireApp().run()
```

**Questionnaire.kv**

```
<Questions>:
    company:company
    department:department

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size:root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:1

            Label:
                id:company

            TextInput:

            Label:
                id:department

            TextInput:

        Button:
            text:"process"
            on_release: root.validate()
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
   File "C:/Users/pavan m sunder/virtual environments/android/Questionnaire.py", line 23, in validate
     self.qvars[i].text = self.Data[i]
 AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I referred to similar questions that had the same error but none matches specifically to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `qvars` list messes things up because it's a list of the property objects, which doesn't have the right behaviour - Kivy Properties are descriptors, they only work at class level.

Instead, just access `self.company` or `self.department` in your methods.

Comment: I tried accessing just self.company and self department initially before posting the question and I had got the expected result but I felt it is not the most efficient way of coding so I asked the question..now it has only 2 question but what if it has like 50 to 100 question..in that case it takes up many lines of code which I feel is not efficient.. Can you suggest any alternative that you feel is the most efficient way.Thanks

Comment: Use a ListProperty instead of a list. And don't add the Property objects to it, just add references to the widgets directly.